# Auto clean up of Text Styles in Sketch / Minimizing amount of styles

Tags: sketch-app, automation, style, plugin, guides

I am working within a sketch file that has 147 different varieties of text styles. Ranging from H1 all the way down to sub categories body text. Now some of them are very similar in style where a variation may be only size text, leading off by a pixel, things like that. My question is: Is there a plugin that allows me to clean it up and if they are similar enough just adjust accordingly thus eliminating the amount of different styles from 147 to lets say 50?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

the plugin from https://labs.invisionapp.com/craft are really helpful to reduce styles. not the original ones from sketch but craft makes its own list you can easily edit

Comment: Hi Petra, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your input. Just a heads-up: if you are affiliated with this plug-in, please mention that in your answer. We really appreciate your input and advice, but we are also very wary of spam and astroturfing. If notm then no harm done! :) If you have questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you (20). Keep contributing and enjoy your time here!

Comment: I'm not affiliated with the Craft Plugin but second that it is a really good plugin to use, even for text styles. I don't want to work without it anymore ;)